# Overriding clicks (such as ng-click) with another ng-click

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a button that calls a function through ng-click.  I want to have a detail 'button' within this button, that when clicked will call a different function through ng-click, BUT NOT THE FIRST FUNCTION.  See this plunker for the problem: http://plnkr.co/edit/CqLmZMKiGPfrvRpqvtMa?p=preview

```
  <button ng-click="sendAlert('button clicked')">
    <span class="text">Demo</span>
    <span class="toggle" ng-click="sendAlert('? clicked')">
          <i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i>
      </span>
  </button>
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ng-click` is just the `click` event underneath and it bubbles up just like many other events. So in you case when you click on the icon inside the button it runs its own click event and bubbles up and executed the click event registered on its parent button as well. You can pass `$event` object and stop the propagation to the parent by doing event.stopPropgation().

Try:

```
<button ng-click="sendAlert($event, 'button clicked')">
  <span class="text">Demo</span>
  <span class="toggle" ng-click="sendAlert($event, 'child')">
      <i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i>
  </span>
</button>
```

and

```
$scope.sendAlert = function(e,alertMessage) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    alert(alertMessage);
  };
```

**[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/2HxZv3?p=preview)**